# GPS Coordinates in 4 bytes

Tags: c++, gps

I am trying to find a method to store the standard Latitude and Longitude (double---both of 8 bytes) in 4 bytes, and viceversa (i.e. convert these data in the standard 8 byte latitude/longitude). Honestly, it is not clear how to do that. I am programming in C++, so if there is an existing function or library to do that, it would be good.

Comment: It depends on the precision (up to 0.005 of degree). Is it just a scaling

Comment: `uint16_t` can hold `0-65535`, if we asssume input range [0,180), you can store them with precision of 0.003 degrees just by scaling by 364 (364*180<65535) and rounding down to nearest integer( i.e. cast will do).

Comment: @Quimby: you need 360 degree for longitude (and you should be careful on handling also negative coordinates)

Comment: While using 16bit for longitude and latitude each would be simple. But say I'm at latitude 89.997°. Do I really need the longitude with 0.006° accuracy? When I'm at the equator though is 0.006° accuracy enough?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow so you suggest modulating the result before truncating? Do you want to check the a-law and mu-law in digital PSTN?

Comment: For optimal results I would suggest using a variable number of bits for latitude and longitude based on the latitude. The aim would be to keep the distance between neighboring points roughly equal across the globe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed point rational representation is a potential solution for this purpose.

There is no fundamental type for fixed point rational numbers, nor does the standard library provide types implementing them. The idea is fairly simple however: Scale the value of an underying integer such that the range of the underlying integer is mapped to the desired range of values.